# add custom item to google places dropdown list - not working in chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

I'm trying to add onclick event on a custom item I add on google places suggestion

I tried this

```
                $('.pac-container').append('<div class="pac-item" _autocomplete_manual onmouseover="alert(888)" onmousedown="console.log(1)"><span class="pac-icon pac-icon-marker" style="visibility:hidden"></span><span  onmousedown="console.log(2)" class="pac-item-query"><span class="pac-matched" style="color:Blue;cursor:hand;z-index:4000;" onmousedown="console.log(3)">Manually enter an address</span></span></div>')
```

It works in firefox and opera, but on chrome, only the onmouseover triggers

any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the developer tools console ?

Comment: Thanks lewis. There's no error. I click it and it triggers the usual autocomplete event, but it doesn't trigger the specified onclick. When I output the onclick of the newly added item (console.log(theaddeditem.onclick)), it does show the onclick event definition